# In what form should make requests to geoserver gml file from javascript?

Tags: geoserver, javascript, gml

In what form should make requests to geoserver gml file from javascript?.

I have made this question, but neither on nor XMLRequest jquery and have downloaded some of geoserver, geoserver values always returns null.

someone will have examples, or know that library is useful for this case.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Is this in any way different from your other question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4134/how-to-download-a-file-from-geoserver-gml-from-a-url-using-javascript/4137#4137? I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give an example of the complete URL sent to geoserver that are not returning data?

Should be something like:
http://sever/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=topp:states&outputFormat=GML2

Comment: Hi Peter:if so are the urls that are entering, and then He must be the url to get the data entry, thanks for your reply